# Fetch nested object property using lodash

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, nested, lodash

I've a nested object with a country code. I need to fetch the corresponding currency property using lodash based on the condition.

I'm a newbie to lodash and not sure which method can I use here.

For e.g., 
When I search for corresponding currencies for the countryCode 'AU', it should return 'AUD'.

Currently, I get the entire object.

How do I get this done?

```js
var myJSON = {
  "countryCode": {
  "Australia": "AU",
  "United States": "US",
  "Britain": "GB",
  "Japan": "JP",
  "India": "IND",
  "France": "FR",
  "Russia": "RS"
},
"countries": {
  "AE": {
    "currencies": {
    "AED": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "AL": {
    "currencies": {
    "ALL": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "AU": {
    "currencies": {
    "AUD": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "US": {
    "currencies": {
    "USD": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "GB": {
    "currencies": {
    "EUR": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "FR": {
    "currencies": {
    "EUR": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "JP": {
    "currencies": {
    "JPY": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "RS": {
    "currencies": {
    "RSD": {
      "isDefault": false
    }
    }
  },
  "ZA": {
    "currencies": {
    "ZAR": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  }
  }
};

function getData() {
 var countryCode = ['AU', 'ZA', 'JP'];
 console.log(_.pick(myJSON.countries, countryCode));
 console.log(_.values(_.pick(myJSON.countries, countryCode))); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
<button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
```

Current Output:
{AU: {…}, ZA: {…}, JP: {…}}

Desired Output:

['AUD', 'ZAR', 'JP']

Here's the code:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lodash way to do it looks like that:

```js
function getData() {
 var countryCode = ['AU', 'ZA', 'JP'];
 console.log(
   _(myJSON.countries)
    .pick(countryCode)
    .values()
    .map(function(value) { return _.keys(value.currencies)[0]; })
    .value()
 ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is giving me countryCodes. I need the currencies.

Comment: Ah, true. Gonna change in in a sec

Comment: I misunderstood it, because of the "Desired Output: ['AUD', 'ZAR', 'JP']"

Comment: Yes, that's how it is supposed to display as per the desired output. But, what I get with your solution is exactly the same as CountryCode.

Answer (score 1):

> When I search for corresponding currencies for the countryCode 'AU',
>   it should return 'AUD'.

Try this vanila js solution as well, use `map`

```
var countryCode = ['AU', 'ZA', 'JP'];
var output = countryCode.map( s => Object.keys( myJSON.countries[ s ].currencies[ 0 ] ) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code won't work in old browsers.

Comment: @Alex due to arrow functions?

Comment: Yep, Object.keys and array.map won't work in olders IEs as well :(

Comment: How old are we talking about? `map` and `Object.keys` are quite old!

Comment: Like in IE8 :D. Actually I like your answer, it should work in 95% of cases, I gave another answer, just only because lodash was already mentioned (and it looks prettier MHO).

Answer (score 0):

Pick will do what its asked to do.

Instead do this :

```
countryCode.map((ct) => Object.keys(myJSON.countries[ct].currencies)[0]);
```